# How to send text with linebreaks coming from user input with PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I need to send text from users typed in a html form (`textarea`) along with emails. I use PHPMailer with HTML setup. This works perfect also because I need to embedd logos. The only problem is that email programs which receive the mail ignores line breaks from this text which. I parse the text like this :

```
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Body =  $_POST['mail_Text'];
```

What do I need to do ?

Comment: May be nl2br() ? : http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Awesome, added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) should work for you.

So, add mail body like this.

```
$mail->Body =  nl2br($_POST['mail_Text']);
```

> **nl2br()** returns string with `<br />` or `<br>` inserted before all newlines (\r\n, \n\r, \n and \r).

Comment: This is correct, but it doesn't explain *why* it works. It's because HTML ignores white space, so runs of spaces, tabs and line breaks are simply collapsed into a single space. `nl2br` converts them to HTML tags that are meaningful.